# Magento2.3.0 Getting error on admin side when save blog

Tags: admin-panel, magento2.3.0, save, blog

I am using third party module mageplaza blog extensions this is an issue when I save in admin side getting error

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): The file was not uploaded.

Exception #0 (Exception): The file was not uploaded.
#0 /var/www/html/XXXXXX/vendor/magento/module-media-storage/Model/File/Uploader.php(58): Magento\Framework\File\Uploader->__construct('image')
#1 /var/www/html/XXXXXX/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(116): Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader->__construct('image', Object(Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database), Object(Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage), Object(Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Validator\NotProtectedExtension))
#2 /var/www/html/XXXXXX/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\MediaSt...', Array)
#3 /var/www/html/XXXXXX/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\MediaSt...', Array)
#4 /var/www/html/XXXXXX/generated/code/Magento/MediaStorage/Model/File/UploaderFactory.php(43): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('\\Magento\\MediaS...', Array)
#5 /var/www/html/XXXXXX/vendor/mageplaza/module-core/Helper/Media.php(108): Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory->create(Array)
#6 /var/www/html/XXXXXX/vendor/mageplaza/magento-2-blog-extension/Controller/Adminhtml/Post/Save.php(138): Mageplaza\Core\Helper\Media->uploadImage(Array, 'image', 'post', NULL)
#7 /var/www/html/XXXXXX/vendor/mageplaza/magento-2-blog-extension/Controller/Adminhtml/Post/Save.php(92): Mageplaza\Blog\Controller\Adminhtml\Post\Save->prepareData(Object(Mageplaza\Blog\Model\Post), Array)
#8 /var/www/html/XXXXXX/generated/code/Mageplaza/Blog/Controller/Adminhtml/Post/Save/Interceptor.php(24): Mageplaza\Blog\Controller\Adminhtml\Post\Save->execute()
#9 /var/www/html/XXXXXX/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(108): Mageplaza\Blog\Controller\Adminhtml\Post\Save\Interceptor->execute()
#10 /var/www/html/XXXXXX/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(231): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#11 /var/www/html/XXXXXX/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#12 /var/www/html/XXXXXX/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Mageplaza\Blog\Controller\Adminhtml\Post\Save\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#13 /var/www/html/XXXXXX/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Mageplaza\Blog\Controller\Adminhtml\Post\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#14 /var/www/html/XXXXXX/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Mageplaza\Blog\Controller\Adminhtml\Post\Save\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#15 /var/www/html/XXXXXX/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Mageplaza\Blog\Controller\Adminhtml\Post\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#16 /var/www/html/XXXXXX/generated/code/Mageplaza/Blog/Controller/Adminhtml/Post/Save/Interceptor.php(39): Mageplaza\Blog\Controller\Adminhtml\Post\Save\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#17 /var/www/html/XXXXXX/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(159): Mageplaza\Blog\Controller\Adminhtml\Post\Save\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#18 /var/www/html/XXXXXX/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(99): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Object(Mageplaza\Blog\Controller\Adminhtml\Post\Save\Interceptor))
#19 /var/www/html/XXXXXX/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20 /var/www/html/XXXXXX/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#21 /var/www/html/XXXXXX/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 /var/www/html/XXXXXX/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#23 /var/www/html/XXXXXX/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /var/www/html/XXXXXX/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#25 /var/www/html/XXXXXX/index.php(44): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#26 {main}
```

If anyone knows please reply to me